# Xcode Base64 Decode issue

Tags: ios, xcode, base64, decode

I have this Base64 decoding code in place -

```
--
 (NSString *)DecodeBase64:(NSString *)Value; {
    //Return the decoded Base64 string.  string must be multiple of 4 chars in length
    NSUInteger paddedLength = Value.length + (4 - (Value.length % 4));
    NSString *paddedBase64 = [Value stringByPaddingToLength:paddedLength withString:@"=" startingAtIndex:0];
    NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:paddedBase64 options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
    NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return decodedString;
}
--
```

Decode of this string -

PD94bWwgdmVyc21vbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvVGluZz0i

returns this string -

```html
<?xml versmon="1.0" encoTing="
```

which appears incorrect, misspell of "version" and "encoding" - 2 incorrect characters.

The source string comes form a very large government body so I don't imagine that it is not correct...

Is there some problem with the code?

Comment: It is actually correct. That string decodes to that snippet. Also, there is no need for you to pad it afaik.. It'll decode properly without you having to manually pad it.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.base64decode.org is giving me the same output so I think you need to check your source again :)